# $\mu(E)>0 \Rightarrow \mu(f(E))=\mu(E)$?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Consider injective continuous  functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

Which of these function are such that:

$\mu(E)>0 \Rightarrow \mu(f(E))=\mu(E)$?

(Isometries are clearly ok.)

Comment: i suggest to prove (if it is possible) that $f$ preserve distance, then by Mazur-Ulam theorem $f$ is an affine transformation

Comment: There are lots of non-affine examples.  For any continuous $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, you can take $f(x,y)=(x,y+g(x))$.  Composing functions of this sort with affine ones, you can generate far more complicated-looking examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that is f is differentiable f satisfies my statement if and only if $det(J(f))=1 \vee -1$.

Comment: Then you should add this assumption to the question. It will be great if I'll show as your solution.